# Why can one define the norm on $C^{k,\alpha}(\partial\Omega)$ by the norm of extensions?

Tags: holder-spaces

I'm reading section 6.2 of Gilbarg and Trudinger's book on elliptic PDEs, where the authors write "$\|u\|_{C^{k,\alpha}(\partial\Omega)} = \inf_{\Phi}\|\Phi\|_{C^{k,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})}$" where $\Phi$ ranges over all extensions of $u$ into $\overline{\Omega}$. However, I don't see how one can prove the triangle inequality with this definition of the norm. Any insight or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $u$ and $v$ are two functions in $C^{1,\alpha}(\partial\Omega)$. For any $\epsilon>0$ there exist extensions $U$ and $V$ such that 
$$\|U\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})}\le \|u\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\partial{\Omega})}+\epsilon, \quad \text{and }\ \|V\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})}\le \|v\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\partial{\Omega})}+\epsilon$$
Then $U+V$ is an extension of $u+v$ and thus 
$$ \|u+v\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\partial{\Omega})} \le 
\|U+V\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})}\le \|u\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\partial{\Omega})}+  \|v\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\partial{\Omega})}+2\epsilon$$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily small, it follows that
$$ \|u+v\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\partial{\Omega})} \le \|u\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\partial{\Omega})}+  \|v\|_{C^{1,\alpha}(\partial{\Omega})} $$
as required.